# Abbreviation for "so-called"

Tags: adjectives, abbreviations, past-participles

In German there is an abbreviation for *so genannt*, which is *sog.*

Is there a known popular abbreviation for the equivalent *so-called* in English?

Comment: Nope, AFAIK *so-called* is about as brief as it gets.

Comment: There is *AKA* (sometimes *aka*) for "also known as", and with a sufficiently sarcastic tone this can be used for *so-called*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None that I know of - therefore definitely not a known popular one.

Answer (score 0):

I have come accross this site a few times on the "so-called" abbreviation query, for I have been interested in it myself, for a while already. However, there still seems to be no clear cut answer, respectively solution offered. So, I'd like to suggest one option, following my experience using it, more frequently nowadays, rspct., a workaround for this.
I want to admit right here, I have not dug the entire inet upside down on this. So, if anyone is willing to share a better way, how to go about this, I appreciate it much. :-)

I eventually introduce it to my texts first as so-called, within here it means pretentous, to claim without the ability and/or standing (law) to provide solid proof, further abbreviated as s.c. or s-c.

Also, a quick inet search unveiled, s.c. seems to be the least used abbreveation variation.

Comment: One reason why s.c. is not used a lot may be that in speaking, it is not an abbreviation. The original so-called has two syllables, and so doe your abbreviation - it shortens nothing in speech an a few measly characters in writing, at the expense of loosing speed for having to read and parse an unknown "abbreviation".